# option.timeout ignored waiting for Selector.withAttribute

Tags: automated-tests, timeout, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I have tried this every which way, but I can't get TestCafe to wait for the `disabled` attribute to be removed from an element.

This obviously blocks all further testing, since I need the button to be clickable before I can proceed in the flow.

```
fixture('create').page('locahost:3000');

test('one', async  => {
  const myIframe = Selector('#myIframe');

  await t
    .typeText('#input', 'words')
    .click('#update')
    .expect(myIframe.exists).ok('', { timeout: 10000 })
    .switchToIframe(myIframe)

  const activeStartButton = await Selector('#start').withAttribute('disabled');

  await t
    .expect(activeStartButton).notOk('', { timeout: 60000, allowUnawaitedPromise: true });
});
```

Regardless of whether I defined `activeStartButton` ahead of time, or add or remove `await` from the definition, put the selector directly in `expect` with or without await, separate this `await block from the previous one or add it to the previous chain, TestCafe immediately throws an error at`expect(activeStartButton).notOk`

The error varies depending on my approach, but for this code:

`AssertionError: start button remains disabled: expected [Function: __$$clientFunction$$] to be falsy"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
const selector = Selector('#start')
    .with({visibilityCheck: true});

await t
    .expect(selector.exists).ok({timeout: 10000}) // ensure the button is visible on the screen
    .hover(selector) // access to the button via the mouse
    .expect(selector.hasAttribute("disabled")).notOk({timeout: 10000}) // ensure the field is enabled
    .click(selector);
```

Maybe you should also have a look to [say goodbye to flakyness](https://github.com/hdorgeval/testcafe-snippets/blob/master/say-goodbye-to-flakyness.md)

Comment: It's worth noting that one of the problems I was having is that `.hasAttribute` is not documented on TestCafe. It's listed as `.withAttribute`, which throws the above error.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
const mySelector = Selector('any css selector');
await t
    .expect(mySelector).notOk()
```

will always throw an error because the truthiness of `mySelector` is always true. So the above code is similar to this code:
`assert(true).toBe(false)`.

Above `mySelector` is a promise object and the truthiness of a promise is always true.

Now if you write:

```
const mySelector = await Selector('any css selector');
await t
    .expect(mySelector).notOk();
```

`mySelector` is a `NodeSnaphsot` object which is some sort of literal object with plenty of properties on it like:

```
{
    textContent,
    attributes,
    id,
    clientHeight,
    ...
}
```

The truthiness of a literal object is always true, and therefore the above 
 `expect` will still throw an error.

In fact, this problem could have been completely masked if the test code was instead:

```
const mySelector = await Selector('any css selector');
await t
    .expect(mySelector).ok();
```

The above test code will always pass even if `mySelector` does not represent any existing element in the DOM.

Inside the expect you should assert only for a property or for a method of the Selector that returns a boolean value when using ok() or notOk().

Possible boolean properties are:

```
mySelector.hasChildElements
mySelector.hasChildNodes
mySelector.checked
mySelector.focused
mySelector.selected
mySelector.visible
mySelector.exists
```

Possible methods are:

```
mySelector.hasClass('className')
mySelector.hasAttribute('attributeName')
```

The `.withAttribute('attributeName') is just a filter method that returns a Selector object (i.e. a Promise) and the truthiness of this result is always true.

So when you are writing :

```
const mySelector = Selector('any css selector').withAttribute('attributeName');
```

it's more or less like writing this pseudo-code:

```
const mySelector = Selector('any css selector') // returns a collection of Selectors
    .toArray() // convert it to an array
    .filter((selector) => selector.hasAttribute('attributeName'))
    .toPromise() // convert back to a promise object
```